# Symbol for skeptical consequence

Tags: symbols, math-operators

I'm looking for a symbol for skeptical consequence so that I can write that something, *B*, is a skeptical consequence of something else, *A*.

In a book I read it's written like `\(A \vdash B\)` or `\(A \sststile{}{} B\)` but the horizontal line is wavy like `\sim`, has the same width as the vertical line and does *not* vary in width. So, what I'm looking for is a binary relation symbol that is similar to the combination of the first two and the last relation in the following image:

[image: I'm looking for the relation symbol that is the synthesis of these]

That is, something similar to the following mockup but the wavy line should be such that it has a constant width and the same width as the vertical line:

[image: Mockup of what I want]

I've tried [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) without success.

Comment: Well, there's always the Big List you can try: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/

Comment: ugly way: `$|\!\!\!\sim$`. This might not scale well...

Comment: @N.N.: Unable to find it anywhere in the comprehensive list...

Comment: Best I've found as yet is ⍭

Comment: There's a follow up to this question at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32244/symbol-for-skeptical-consequence-that-matches-the-turnstile-package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe seems similar to the [nonmonotonic inference relation symbol used in this paper](http://www.cs.ubbcluj.ro/~studia-i/2010-4/05-Lupea.pdf).  The main difference being that this a small space between the two characters, which I think actually looks better than having them touch.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\nc}[2]{#1\mathbin{\left| \sim \vphantom{#1#2} \right.}#2}%

\begin{document}
$\nc{A}{B} \qquad \nc{\frac{A}{C}}{B}$
\end{document}
```

---

**Update:** Here is a version where both the straight and wavy line are re-sized and the two symbols touch:

[image]

I have used `\scalebox` from the `\graphicx` package to resize the symbols (resize horizontally for the wavy line and vertically for the vertical bar) based on the height of the operands on either side.  The `\mathrlap` is obtained from a TUGboat 22 article entitled [a complement to \smash, \llap, and \rlap](http://math.arizona.edu/~aprl/publications/mathclap/).  I am not an expert in the use of the `rlap` type command, so perhaps some of the resize code could be simplified.  I also used `pgf` to do the math, and this is probably overkill but I am more familiar with that then doing math in plain TeX.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}%  only needed for \dfrac
\usepackage{graphicx}% needed for \scalebox
\usepackage{pgf}%      needed for the math calculations

% http://math.arizona.edu/~aprl/publications/mathclap/
\def\mathrlap{\mathpalette\mathrlapinternal}%
\def\mathrlapinternal#1#2{\rlap{$\mathsurround=0pt#1{#2}$}}%

\makeatletter
\newdimen\@mydimen%
\newdimen\@myHeightOfBar%
\settoheight{\@myHeightOfBar}{$|$}%
\newcommand{\SetScaleFactor}[1]{%
    \settoheight{\@mydimen}{#1}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\scaleFactor}{\@mydimen/\@myHeightOfBar}%
}%

\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][3]{\scalebox{#1}{\ensuremath{#2}}}%

\newcommand*{\nct}[2]{%
    \SetScaleFactor{\vphantom{\ensuremath{#1#2}}}% Compute scale to be applied
    #1%
\mathrel{\Scale[\scaleFactor]{|\mathrlap{\kern-0.48ex\sim}\hphantom{\kern-0.41ex\sim}}}%
    #2%
}%

\begin{document}
$\nct{a}{b}  \qquad \nct{\frac{A}{C}}{B}  \qquad \nct{\dfrac{A}{C}}{B}$
\end{document}
```

---

An enhanced version of this solution that allows you to specify a character to be placed above and below the wavy line is available at the follow-up question: [Symbol for skeptical consequence that matches the turnstile package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32244/symbol-for-skeptical-consequence-that-matches-the-turnstile-package/32282#32282)

---

Comment: The book I found the symbol in treats the same topic as the article you link, that is, default logic. I think what would look best is having them connected but the wavy sign being constant in width and having the same width as the vertical line.

Comment: @N.N.: Have updated the solution where the vertical and wavy lines touch and both get resized.

Comment: Maybe it would be more correct to define the symbol with `\mathrel` rather than `\mathbin`? It expresses a relation rather than an operation. But maybe I'm wrong, my only knowledge of types of math symbols is from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21336/math-mode-accents-and-spacing/21339#21339

Comment: Good point. Have updated it to use `\mathrel`. Also took this opportunity to fix the horizontal spacing issue present in the earlier solution.

Comment: In the equation with `\dfrac` the left edge of `\sim` is noticeable but it's not in the other equations. Is this possible to fix?

Comment: @N.N.: Have updated the code to adjust that. However, am not yet able to update image due to imgur problems.

Comment: Just tried it, looks much better!

Comment: Image now updated.

Answer (score 5):

The following uses `\medvert` and a clipped version of `\sim` from the [`MnSymbol` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mnsymbol). Clipping is provided by [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox)'s `\clipbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mnsymbol
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{adjustbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox
\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\skepcon}{\ensuremath{\mathrel{\medvert\mskip-5.7mu\clipbox{1 0 0 0}{$\sim$}}}}
$A\skepcon B$
\end{document}
```

These two symbols have the same fixed width, as opposed to the varied width of `\sim` when *not* loading `MnSymbol`.

Comment: Is it possible to fix so that the left bottom edge of `\sim` is not not noticable as it merges with `\medvert`? I want them to look as they're one symbol rather than two merged.

Comment: @N.N.: I've updated my answer to clip the `\sim` symbol using [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox)'s `\clipbox` macro.

Answer (score 2):

[This site](http://gregorywheeler.org/latex/phil-style2.html) recommends:

```
\newcommand{\nc}{\,\mid\!\sim\,}
```

Though perhaps it would be worth wrapping it in a `\mathrel` or something for proper spacing?