# A question on how to scale some turnstiles from the turnstile package

Tags: tikzscale, turnstile

The edit of the accepted answer for question [Symbol for skeptical consequence that matches the turnstile package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32244/symbol-for-skeptical-consequence-that-matches-the-turnstile-package) gives me access to the two first turnstiles in the MWE below. I would appreciate help with scaling these in the way expressed in the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{turnstile}% http://ctan.org/pkg/turnstile

\usepackage{tikz}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf

\usepackage{adjustbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox

\renewcommand{\makehor}[4]
{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{n}}{\hspace{#3}}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{s}}{\rule[-0.5#2]{#3}{#2}}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{d}}{\setlength{\lengthvar}{#2}
        \addtolength{\lengthvar}{0.5#4}
        \rule[-\lengthvar]{#3}{#2}
        \hspace{-#3}
        \rule[0.5#4]{#3}{#2}}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{t}}{\setlength{\lengthvar}{1.5#2}
        \addtolength{\lengthvar}{#4}
        \rule[-\lengthvar]{#3}{#2}
        \hspace{-#3}
        \rule[-0.5#2]{#3}{#2}
        \hspace{-#3}
        \setlength{\lengthvar}{0.5#2}
        \addtolength{\lengthvar}{#4}
        \rule[\lengthvar]{#3}{#2}}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{w}}{% New wavy $\sim$ definition
        \setbox0=\hbox{$\sim$}%
        \raisebox{-.6ex}{\hspace*{-.05ex}\adjustbox{width=#3,height=\height}{\clipbox{0.75 0 0 0}{\usebox0}}}}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{z}}{% New tikz wavy definition
        \raisebox{-.4ex}{\hspace*{-.08ex}\tikz \draw [thin,x=0.5ex,y=.25ex] (0,0) sin (1,1) cos (2,0) sin (3,-1) cos (4,0);\hspace*{.2ex}}}{}   
}

\begin{document}
    I want $\turnstile{s}{s}{}{}{n}B$ and $ A\turnstile{s}{z}{}{}{n}B$ to be scaled so that the size and height of the vertical line and fatness of the lines become  as in the standard turnstile $\vdash$. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach with the `scalerel` package, used to define `\xturnstile{}{}{}{}{}`.  And it even works across mathstyles.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{turnstile}% http://ctan.org/pkg/turnstile

\usepackage{tikz}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf

\usepackage{adjustbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox

\usepackage{scalerel}

\renewcommand{\makehor}[4]
{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{n}}{\hspace{#3}}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{s}}{\rule[-0.5#2]{#3}{#2}}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{d}}{\setlength{\lengthvar}{#2}
        \addtolength{\lengthvar}{0.5#4}
        \rule[-\lengthvar]{#3}{#2}
        \hspace{-#3}
        \rule[0.5#4]{#3}{#2}}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{t}}{\setlength{\lengthvar}{1.5#2}
        \addtolength{\lengthvar}{#4}
        \rule[-\lengthvar]{#3}{#2}
        \hspace{-#3}
        \rule[-0.5#2]{#3}{#2}
        \hspace{-#3}
        \setlength{\lengthvar}{0.5#2}
        \addtolength{\lengthvar}{#4}
        \rule[\lengthvar]{#3}{#2}}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{w}}{% New wavy $\sim$ definition
        \setbox0=\hbox{$\sim$}%
        \raisebox{-.6ex}{\hspace*{-.05ex}\adjustbox{width=#3,height=\height}{\clipbox{0.75 0 0 0}{\usebox0}}}}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{z}}{% New tikz wavy definition
        \raisebox{-.4ex}{\hspace*{-.08ex}\tikz \draw [thin,x=0.5ex,y=.25ex] (0,0) sin (1,1) cos (2,0) sin (3,-1) cos (4,0);\hspace*{.2ex}}}{}   
}

\newcommand\xturnstile[5]{\mathrel{\scalerel*{\turnstile{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}{\vdash}}}

\begin{document}
    I want $\xturnstile{s}{s}{}{}{n}B$ and $ A\xturnstile{s}{z}{}{}{n}B$ to be scaled 
    so that the size and height of the vertical line and fatness of the lines become 
    as in the standard turnstile $\vdash$. 

\[
A\xturnstile{s}{z}{}{}{n}B \quad\scriptstyle
A\xturnstile{s}{z}{}{}{n}B \quad\scriptscriptstyle
A\xturnstile{s}{z}{}{}{n}B
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I see that ideally I would have liked the tilde to be even more exaggerated so that there would be no danger for mistaking $\xturnstile{s}{z}{}{}{n}B$ for$\xturnstile{s}{w}{}{}{n}B$ - or vice versa.