# \vdash and \models with curly horizontal lines

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

How can I create the `\vdash` and `\models` math symbols with curly horizontal lines similar to `\approx`?

Solution: \def\modelx{\mathrel|\joinrel\approx}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a compilable short code ...

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32244/symbol-for-skeptical-consequence-that-matches-the-turnstile-package.

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\vapprox}{\mathrel{\scalebox{1}[1.5]{$\shortmid$}\mkern-3.1mu\raisebox{0.1ex}{$\approx$}}}
\newcommand{\vsim}{\mathrel{\scalebox{1}[1.5]{$\shortmid$}\mkern-3.1mu\raisebox{0.15ex}{$\sim$}}}

\begin{document}

    \[ A \vapprox B\vsim C\quad \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks nice, except that \shortmid is a bit too short--how can I make the line a bit longer?

Comment: You just change the optional argument of `scalebox` (it is a vertical scaling of 1.5). Note I managed to get it the same height as the vertical rule of `\vdash`.

Comment: That's true for \vdash, but unfortunately not for \vapprox; with a scalebox of 2.2 and a raisebox of 0.4ex, \vapprox looks pretty good, except that the symbol is now printed too high..