# \Vdash with a tilde instead of a horizontal line?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, typography, tilde

I'm basically looking for a nicely type-set version of the symbol `||~`, or a way to make it myself.

Is there a way to generate a math-mode symbol that looks like a `\VDash`, but with a tilde in place of a horizontal line?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31466/symbol-for-skeptical-consequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? EDITED to make it a  `\mathbin` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,amssymb}
\def\Vsym{\mathbin{{\vert}\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\mkern-1.5mu\vert}{\sim}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}}}
\begin{document}
\[
a \mathbin{\Vsym} b
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]