# Symbol for an admissible rule in logic

Tags: symbols, logic

Could you please help me find a specific symbol (see the picture below) for an admissible rule in mathamatical logic? We can write for it `|\!\!\!\sim`, but I want the vertical dash to be the same size as $\vdash$. Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which documentclass do you use, do you compile with pdflatex, lualatex or xelatex?

Comment: Thank you! I use pdflatex, documentclass is article.

Comment: Add a compilable code because we do not know where you are coming from.

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate of the question it's been linked to. Was a different question intended as the duplicate? As far as I can tell, the linked question has nothing to do with this one except that they both concern turnstiles in logic.

Comment: @Inv619, please add the requested code to qualify for reopening: more often than not the preamble is important to know. Thank you

Comment: I think the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32118/ is better as a duplicate, as it is the same vertical size as `\vdash` which was what was asked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you could resort to the package `logix` and the command `\TurnWavy` ("wavy turnstile"). It's a binary relation, which I believe is how you are using it.

[`logix`](https://ctan.org/pkg/logix?lang=en) just provides a Unicode font; LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX let you input Unicode characters directly into your source (*and* show up as intended in the output).

Source: [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbols List, p. 81](https://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf#page=83); I found it by looking up variants of "turnstile" in the index.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, do you have a solution that does not change  pdflatex? Could we just add a new symbol with an additional code in the preambula? (I work with \usepackage[english,russian]{babel} and it conflicts with others compilators).

Comment: @lnv619 Babel works fine with lualatex etc. (you might have to pick a suitable font)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It worked! Thank you! I added  
`\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Renderer=Basic,Ligatures={TeX}]{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont[Renderer=Basic,Ligatures={TeX,Historic}]{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}`

Comment: @lnv619 You're welcome! Don't forget to accept @ marquinho's answer if your problem is solved :)

Comment: For the record, you don't need XeTeX or LuaTeX to use unicode in your *source*. The problem is pdfTeX can't use a unicode font for output.

Comment: @cfr: Thanks! Will edit accordingly